# Calculate Smart Group of boxes with min max points

Tags: java, algorithm, bounding-box

I have List of boundary boxes with min max point for example:

```
    public class BoundaryVolume {
    
        public Point3D min;
        public Point3D max;
    }

BoundaryVolume  Box1 = new BoundaryVolume ( new Point3D (5,10,15), new Point3D (30,50,100));
BoundaryVolume  Box2 = new BoundaryVolume ( new Point3D (-30,-10,-15), new Point3D (30,50,100));
BoundaryVolume  Box3 = new BoundaryVolume ( new Point3D (225,-50, -15), new Point3D (1000,0 , 0));
BoundaryVolume  Box4 = new BoundaryVolume ( new Point3D (0,0,0), new Point3D (1,1,1));
List<BoundaryVolume> = new List<BoundaryVolume>().add(Box1).add(Box2).add(Box3).add(Box4)
```

I want to group recursively  this boxes to group of groups in a smart way calculation

```
Geometries geos2 = new Geometries(A, B, C);
Geometries geos3 = new Geometries(D, E);
Geometries geos1 = new Geometries(geos2, F, geos3);
```

Box that nearby another box make them in same box.
How can I do it

What I need is to get list of Boxes and to make a List of lists. demo of my need is in attach image.

[image]

Comment: "Box that nearby another box make them in same box" - what do you mean by that? What is `Geometries` class, with what fields? With which part do you have problems? In checking if something is contained in something else?

Comment: The Geomeries is just list of boxes, I edit the question maybe it will be more clear

Comment: You need to come up with some condition that defines whether two rectangles are in the same group. Most likely you could just use a distance - calculating distance between two rectangles shouldn't be too hard. Then you just check all pairs of rectangles and assign to the same group. However, there could be some weird edge cases which I don't know how you want to handle, eg. big ring of squares and a single tiny square in the middle - are those two groups or one?