# Find Distance Between two boundary box with min max point

Tags: java, algorithm, geometry, bounding-box

in addition to my prev question here [Calculate Smart Group of boxes with min max points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62548949/calculate-smart-group-of-boxes-with-min-max-points) I try to find the distance between 2 boxes:

This is my class of box

```
public class BoundaryVolume {
    public Point3D min;
    public Point3D max;
}
```

first step I find if there are overlap, then I return 0
otherwise I try to find the distance

This is my code:

```
public static double getDistance(BoundaryVolume box1 , BoundaryVolume box2) {
    if(doOverlap(box1 ,box2)) return 0;
    double dis1 = box1.min.distance(box2.min);
    double dis2 = box1.min.distance(box2.max);
    double dis3 = box1.max.distance(box2.min);
    
    double dis4 = box1.max.distance(box2.max);
    double min_disatnce = dis1;
    if(dis2 < min_disatnce) min_disatnce = dis2;
    if(dis3 < min_disatnce) min_disatnce = dis3;
    if(dis4 < min_disatnce) min_disatnce = dis4;
    return min_disatnce;
    
}
public static boolean doOverlap(BoundaryVolume box1 , BoundaryVolume box2)  
{ 
    double x5  = Math.max(box1.min.get_x().get(), box2.min.get_x().get()); 
    double y5  = Math.max(box1.min.get_y().get(), box2.min.get_y().get()); 
    double x6  = Math.min(box1.max.get_x().get(), box2.max.get_x().get()); 
    double y6  = Math.min(box1.max.get_y().get(), box2.max.get_y().get()); 

  
    // no intersection 
    if (x5 > x6 || y5 > y6)  
    { 
        System.out.println("No intersection"); 
        return false; 
    } 
    System.out.println("Has intersection"); 
    return true; 
}
```

I get this:
**The distance between [(-350.0, -500.0, 0.0),(350.0, 200.0, 0.0)] and [(-30.0, -680.0, -90.0),(130.0, -520.0, 70.0)] is 378.02116342871597**
and seems that this is wrong,

I try to find what is not working in those 2 functions

Comment: You dont reqlly calculate the min distance since you just look at the distance beetwen the  coner, not taking edges in count.

Comment: I'll try to make a solution that work by basicly you have to look for the 2 closest corner like you did, then, take on of thoses 2 coner and return his min distance with the edges next to the other corner.

Comment: If you can guide me more what to do for fixing it will help me greatly, thanks

Comment: I make a explain answer. You will have to chance a bit BoundaryVolume

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You calculte the distance a. But the real min distance is b or c.

Also you only check the distance beetwen top-left and bottom-right coners :
[image]

In this example you calculate a or b (same distance). whe you sould calculate c, but he real min distance is d or e after.

Insted of looking for 2 dimenttion just searche the shorter distance between x and y of your coner.
Shortter distance of :

```
box1_max_x > box2_min_x
box1_max_y > box2_min_y
box2_max_y > box1_min_y
box2_max_y > box1_min_y
box1_max_x > box2_max_x
box1_max_y > box2_max_y
box2_min_y > box1_min_y
box2_min_y > box1_min_y
```

Comment: I have just the bottom left (as min point) and top right (as max point), I know that it possible getting the distance just with those 2 points. but I miss something and I don't know what, Thanks

Comment: Its is possible you right. You can deduce the coodiante of the 2 other corner with it. I modify the answer

Comment: In fact you just do all the possible combination